# MS Access and google info graphics

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to have a form/report display an image using the google info graphics APi. So I'm just looking for how I can display a URL image on a form. Alternatively, I'd be happy to copy the image to a local drive, then to display the image from there.

here's some info about the API, it's pretty slick https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?hl=en

All I'm really after is a way to generate QRs and add them to a report. So if someone knows a good QR add-in I would be more than happy to explore that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web browser control in MS Access.

[image: web browser]

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Me.WebBrowser0.ControlSource = "=""https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world&choe=UTF-8"""
End Sub
```

More: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/add-web-browsing-to-a-form-HA101631434.aspx

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks a great start, thanks @Remou. Of course now I'm realizing that I really need it in a report. I know web browsers can't go in reports though. Any other ideas?